# Math symbol explanation in the same line

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

I would like to write the explanation of symbols on the same line of the equation.

I would like to see something like this:

[image]
This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 K_0 = \frac{\sum x}{n} && \text{where, $x_i$ - raw yaw angle at idle state} \label{eq:2} \\
 \text{$n$ - total number of measurements}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally would not add that as a part of the equation as there is often limited space available. If you insist, you could do something like

```
\begin{equation}
 K_0 = \frac{\sum x}{n} \qquad  \text{where,}\quad
 \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
   &x_i &&\text{ -- raw yaw angle at idle state}
   \\
   & n &&\text{ -- total number of measurements}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd simply use a `tabular`. Two versions, one with the equation number centered as a whole, one with top alignment of the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:center}
\begin{gathered}
K_0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i
\qquad\text{where}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
$x_i$ & -- raw yaw angle at idle state \\
$n$   & -- total number of measurements
\end{tabular}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:top}
K_0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i
\qquad\text{where}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
$x_i$ & -- raw yaw angle at idle state \\
$n$   & -- total number of measurements
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I found another way.

```
\begin{align} % multi-line equation
     K_0 = \frac{\sum x}{n} \label{eq:311} \quad \text{where,} 
        & \text{ $x_i$ - raw yaw angle at idle state}\\
        & \text{$n$ - total number of measurements}\nonumber
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could add an image to show how your answer parses

Comment: @mrbolichi I have it  now.